# WebView fails with net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE

Tags: android, android-webview, android-9.0-pie

I try to load an URL in WebView but when load URL first time its give **net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE**  error.

However, when I run the app for the Second time, the WebView load URL correctly:

```
mWebView = new WebView(mContextWraper);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.clearHistory();
        mWebView.clearFormData();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mWebView.getSettings().setSafeBrowsingEnabled(false);
        }
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(0);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }
```

Any help, suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have any cache on first time. You can try below code...

```
try
{
 mWebView.clearCache(true);
}
catch(Exception ex){
//print a log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happen in android P.
Add this line in Manifest file to solve this issue

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```